# how to read and store elements from a text file and store it another file using regexp in tcl

Tags: tcl

This is the given table
I need to extract "index_1" , "index_2" and "values" information in another file using regexp in tcl

```
internal_power() {
  related_pin : "B0";
  rise_power(energy_template_7x7) {
    index_1 ("0.008, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.224, 0.28");
    index_2 ("0.01, 0.06, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3");
    values ( \
      "0.002669, 0.002702, 0.002704, 0.002706, 0.002707, 0.002707, 0.002707", \
      "0.002652, 0.002695, 0.002699, 0.002701, 0.002703, 0.002703, 0.002704", \
      "0.002701, 0.002737, 0.002744, 0.002748, 0.00275, 0.002751, 0.002752", \
      "0.002789, 0.002814, 0.002821, 0.002823, 0.002825, 0.002826, 0.002827", \
      "0.002923, 0.002914, 0.002915, 0.002919, 0.002921, 0.002922, 0.002922", \
      "0.00311, 0.003083, 0.003085, 0.003085, 0.003086, 0.003087, 0.003088", \
      "0.003288, 0.003249, 0.00325, 0.003265, 0.003265, 0.003264, 0.003249");
  }
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Please read the [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is pretty close to being valid Tcl syntax. One cool thing about Tcl is that it's pretty easy to define a DSL: you need to override the default [`unknown`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/unknown.htm) procedure.

I bet the data you posted is just a snippet of your actual data, so you'll have to adjust this accordingly.

The data file "data.txt"

```
internal_power() {
  related_pin : "B0";
  rise_power(energy_template_7x7) {
    index_1 ("0.008, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.224, 0.28");
    index_2 ("0.01, 0.06, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3");
    values ( \
      "0.002669, 0.002702, 0.002704, 0.002706, 0.002707, 0.002707, 0.002707", \
      "0.002652, 0.002695, 0.002699, 0.002701, 0.002703, 0.002703, 0.002704", \
      "0.002701, 0.002737, 0.002744, 0.002748, 0.00275, 0.002751, 0.002752", \
      "0.002789, 0.002814, 0.002821, 0.002823, 0.002825, 0.002826, 0.002827", \
      "0.002923, 0.002914, 0.002915, 0.002919, 0.002921, 0.002922, 0.002922", \
      "0.00311, 0.003083, 0.003085, 0.003085, 0.003086, 0.003087, 0.003088", \
      "0.003288, 0.003249, 0.00325, 0.003265, 0.003265, 0.003264, 0.003249");
  }
}
```

The Tcl script "data.tcl"

```
rename unknown _orig_unknown
proc unknown {cmd args} {
    switch -glob -- $cmd {
        internal_power* - rise_power* { 
            # handle "extra characters after close-quote" error
            set code [regsub -all {("[^"]*")(\S)} [lindex $args 0] {\1 \2}]   ; # " appease syntax highlighter
            eval $code
        }
        related_pin {}
        index_1 - index_2 - values {
            dict set ::data $cmd [regexp -inline -all {[\d.-]+} [join $args]]
        }
        default {_orig_unknown $cmd {*}$args}
    }
}

set data [dict create]
source data.txt                  ; # execute the txt file as code.
dict for {cmd values} $data {
    puts "for $cmd, I have [llength $values] values"
    puts "    $values"
}
```

Executing it

```
$ tclsh data.tcl 
for index_1, I have 7 values
    0.008 0.04 0.08 0.12 0.16 0.224 0.28
for index_2, I have 7 values
    0.01 0.06 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3
for values, I have 49 values
    0.002669 0.002702 0.002704 0.002706 0.002707 0.002707 0.002707 0.002652 0.002695 0.002699 0.002701 0.002703 0.002703 0.002704 0.002701 0.002737 0.002744 0.002748 0.00275 0.002751 0.002752 0.002789 0.002814 0.002821 0.002823 0.002825 0.002826 0.002827 0.002923 0.002914 0.002915 0.002919 0.002921 0.002922 0.002922 0.00311 0.003083 0.003085 0.003085 0.003086 0.003087 0.003088 0.003288 0.003249 0.00325 0.003265 0.003265 0.003264 0.003249
```

Of course, with `eval`, you have to be careful about the presence of malicious code in the data file.

Comment: Safe interpreters can tame most of the hazards of malicious code, especially when coupled up with an execution time limit.